# Add delay to mousemove event

Tags: javascript, events, mousemove

I  have this function running on a mousemove event. The functionality is to iterate a list of images and move to the top (z-index) each one at a time. This is working right but my problem is that the script is running really fast and the images displays really fast. How can I add a delay to the function or the event? I tried with setTimeOut with no positive effects

Here's the code

```
// creating variables
const imgQty = 6;
const holder = document.getElementById('holder')
var counter = 1;
var isMoving = false;
var bgtimeout, imgtimeout;
var bkgImgs = []

// this creates the containers for each img

for (let i = 1; i <= imgQty; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add('background')
    newDiv.classList.add(`background--${i}`)
    newDiv.setAttribute("style", `background-image: url('imgs/${i}.jpg'); z-index: 0;`);
    holder.appendChild(newDiv);
    bkgImgs.push(newDiv)
}

//this moves the counter and also hides the images when the mouse is not moving

function changeBkg(e){
    counter >= imgQty ? counter = 1 : counter++

    holder.classList.add('isActive')
    clearTimeout(bgtimeout);
    clearTimeout(imgtimeout);

    bgtimeout = setTimeout(function(){holder.classList.remove('isActive')}, 150);
        
    moveImgs();

}

// and here is where my issue is, this function is working but not as I expected

function moveImgs(){

    for(var i = 0; i < bkgImgs.length; i++){
            if(bkgImgs[i].classList.contains(`background--${counter}`)){
                    bkgImgs[i].style.zIndex = "1";
            } else{
                bkgImgs[i].style.zIndex = "0";
            }
    }

}
```

Is my logic right? or do I have to rethink the code?

the event is fired in the section:

```
<section class="main" onmousemove="changeBkg(event)"></section>
```

Comment: I would recommend not to use the mouse move event, onmouseenter and onmouseleave are much easier to control and have less impact on the performance

Answer (score 1):

Use [Debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce)

Something like this should work (remove the timeout from inside changeBkg):

```
//change 300ms to suite your needs
<section class="main" onmousemove="debounce(changeBkg(event),300)"></section>
```

> A debounce is a higher-order function, which is a function that returns another function. This is done to form a closure around the func , wait , and immediate function parameters and the timeout variable so that their values are preserved.

Further reading/if you prefer to implement yourself: [Debounce Article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086)

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved. 
As what I needed was some sort of animation I figured it out using greensock
So my event have inside this animation that triggers when animPlay is true and when is playing remains false

```
        if(animPlay){
        animPlay = false
        var tl = new TimelineMax();
        tl.staggerFromTo(bkgImgs, .5, {zIndex:0}, {zIndex:1}, .15, 0)
        .set(bkgImgs, {zIndex:0, onComplete:() => animPlay = true}, '+=0' )

    }
```